# java why does an enhanced for loop iterate over null results in a HashMap with more than 16 or more items?

Tags: java, foreach, nullpointerexception, iteration

The code I used originally, which returned a NullPointerException in some places for any HashMap containing 16 or more elements:

```
for(Entry<Integer, String> e : myHashMap.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": "+e.getValue());
}
```

The code I am now using, which works on the same HashMap, regardless of size:

```
int i = 0; //variable to show the index
int c = 0; //variable to count the number items found
while(c < myHashMap.size()){
    if(myHashMap.containsKey(i)){ //if the HashMap contains the key i
        System.out.println(i + ": "+myHashMap.get(i)); //Print found item
        c++; //increment up to count the number of objects found
    }
    i++; //increment to iterate to the next key
}
```

What is the difference between the two? Why does the first one iterate over null values? And, more importantly, why does the first one iterate out of order if there are 16 or more items? (ie: 12,13,17,15,16,19,18 instead of the neat 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 in the second)

I think I am just starting to scratch the surface of java, so I would like to understand why it was designed this way. Any book recommendations on this kind of thing are welcome.

Comment: You need to show us how you populated the `HashMap`.

Comment: What exactly did the exception look like? As for ordering: `HashMap` is unordered. You shouldn't *expect* to get values out in any particular order.

Comment: I populated the HashMap in order, manually via prompt, starting at key:value 1:"one", then 2:"two", etc. It printed null values first. What I am wondering is what the key difference between those two methods of iteration are? Shouldn't they have the same result, or is this something I need to learn about java?

Comment: For collections, the `foreach` method of iteration (your first example) uses the `iterator()` method from the collection.  Also, you should be doing `System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());` if you want to see what each key maps to.  This may help you determine why the null is occuring, as well.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake from my copy/paste. I edited it to get rid of the other code that ran in there. I did have e.getKey() in there originally. *edited!

Comment: I think your best bet (especially since it's just maps of size 16 or more) is going to be to use a debugger and step through it to find where the null is.  The only way you would be getting an NPE is if e is null, which doesn't make sense to me.  

The reason the first one is out of order is because the iterator isn't guaranteed to have any order in a `HashMap` (at least, relative to how you insert the keys).  You can use a `LinkedHashMap` if you want them to be extracted in the same order you input them.

Comment: In other words, the magic number of 16 is an accident? That is odd because I have run into this same problem with 16 on HashMaps in three different cases. Could it be a problem with my JVM?

Comment: If you can produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits this behavior, perhaps someone can try it independently to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation of a class and try to understand its purpose before starting to use it. `HashMap` provides an efficient storage but *no guaranteed order*. It’s just a coincident that you didn't discover it with smaller `HashMap` sizes because the default capacity is `16` and the hash codes of contiguous `Integer` objects are contiguous too. But that is not a property you can rely on. You always have to assume no guaranteed order for a `HashMap`.

If you need the insertion order you can use a `LinkedHashMap`, if you need ascending order of the keys you can use a `TreeMap`. If you have a contiguous range of `Integer` keys and want ascending order you can simply use an array as well.

The foreach loop `for(Entry<Integer, String> e : myHashMap.entrySet())` does not “iterate over null values”. It iterates over the values *contained* in the `HashMap` which are the values you have added before. There can be at most one `null` key contained in the map, if you added it. You might see `null` values in the debugger when looking at the internal array of a `HashMap` which are *unused* slots as a `HashMap` has a *capacity* which can be larger than its *size*.